# My code doesn’t work when I put in in a function in python

Tags: python, function, loops

I have a code that does a sliding window binning, it works when I use it outside the function, but when I put it in the function it only fills the first line and then it stops working.

```
def slidefunc (data,window,step):
    minmz = data['mass'].min()
    maxmz = data['mass'].max()
    bins = []
    minbin = minmz+window
    maxbin = maxmz-window
    for i in np.arange(minbin,maxbin,step):
        bins.append(i)
    m = len(bins)-1
    i = 0
    j = 0
    first = 0
    n = 0
    accum = 0
    mzbins = pd.DataFrame(bins, columns= ['bins'])
    mzbins['intensity'] = np.nan
    mzbins['samples'] = np.nan

    while (j<=m):
        lower = bins[j]- window
        upper = bins[j]+ window
        while data.iat[i,0]<= lower:
            i = i + 1
        first = i
        while data.iat[i,0]< upper:            
            accum = accum + data.iat[i,1]
            n = n + 1
            i = i + 1
        if (n>0):
            mzbins.iat[j,1] = accum/n
            mzbins.iat[j,2] = n
            #a = accum/n
            #b = n
            accum = 0 
            n = 0
        j = j + 1
        i = first
            # Jump empty regions
        #empty =   mzbins.iat[j,0]+window
        #while j<m and data.iat[i,0] > empty :
         #   j = j + 1

        return mzbins
```

Comment: how you're executing it outside of function ?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36937869/sliding-window-over-pandas-dataframe for alternative approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the last line

```
        return mzbins
```

is indented too much and should be outside the `while` loop, i.e.

```
    return mzbins
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem, I come from R and I’m still struggling with indent.